# Hive doesn't read partitioned parquet files generated by Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, partitioning, partition, parquet

I'm having a problem to read partitioned parquet files generated by Spark in Hive. I'm able to create the external table in hive but when I try to select a few lines, hive returns only an "OK" message with no rows.

I'm able to read the partitioned parquet files correctly in Spark, so I'm assuming that they were generated correctly.
I'm also able to read these files when I create an external table in hive without partitioning.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

**My Environment is:**

- Cluster EMR 4.1.0
- Hive 1.0.0
- Spark 1.5.0
- Hue 3.7.1
- Parquet files are stored in a S3 bucket (s3://staging-dev/test/ttfourfieldspart2/year=2013/month=11)

**My Spark config file has the following parameters(/etc/spark/conf.dist/spark-defaults.conf):**

```
spark.master yarn
spark.driver.extraClassPath /etc/hadoop/conf:/etc/hive/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*
spark.driver.extraLibraryPath /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native
spark.executor.extraClassPath /etc/hadoop/conf:/etc/hive/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*
spark.executor.extraLibraryPath /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps
spark.history.fs.logDirectory hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps
spark.yarn.historyServer.address ip-10-37-161-246.ec2.internal:18080
spark.history.ui.port 18080
spark.shuffle.service.enabled true
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions    -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'
spark.executor.memory 4G
spark.driver.memory 4G
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors 100
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors 1
```

**Hive config file has the following parameters(/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml):**

```
<configuration>

<!-- Hive Configuration can either be stored in this file or in the hadoop configuration files  -->
<!-- that are implied by Hadoop setup variables.                                                -->
<!-- Aside from Hadoop setup variables - this file is provided as a convenience so that Hive    -->
<!-- users do not have to edit hadoop configuration files (that may be managed as a centralized -->
<!-- resource).                                                                                 -->

<!-- Hive Execution Parameters -->


<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <value>ip-10-xx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal</value>
  <description>http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hive/HBaseIntegration</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
  <value>mr</value>
</property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://ip-10-xx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal:8020</value>
  </property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <value>thrift://ip-10-xx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal:9083</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://ip-10-xx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
    <description>username to use against metastore database</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</value>
    <description>username to use against metastore database</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hive</value>
  <description>username to use against metastore database</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>1R72JFCDG5XaaDTB</value>
  <description>password to use against metastore database</description>
</property>

  <property>
    <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
    <value>-1</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapred.max.split.size</name>
    <value>256000000</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.connect.retries</name>
    <value>5</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hive.optimize.sort.dynamic.partition</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property><name>hive.exec.dynamic.partition</name><value>true</value></property>
  <property><name>hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode</name><value>nonstrict</value></property>
  <property><name>hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions</name><value>10000</value></property>
  <property><name>hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode</name><value>500</value></property>

</configuration>
```

**My python code that reads the partitioned parquet file:**

```
from pyspark import *
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df7 = sqlContext.read.parquet('s3://staging-dev/test/ttfourfieldspart2/')
```

**The parquet file schema printed by Spark:**

```
>>> df7.schema
StructType(List(StructField(transactionid,StringType,true),StructField(eventts,TimestampType,true),StructField(year,IntegerType,true),StructField(month,IntegerType,true)))

>>> df7.printSchema()
root
 |-- transactionid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- eventts: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- year: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- month: integer (nullable = true)

>>> df7.show(10)
+--------------------+--------------------+----+-----+
|       transactionid|             eventts|year|month|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+-----+
|f7018907-ed3d-49b...|2013-11-21 18:41:...|2013|   11|
|f6d95a5f-d4ba-489...|2013-11-21 18:41:...|2013|   11|
|02b2a715-6e15-4bb...|2013-11-21 18:41:...|2013|   11|
|0e908c0f-7d63-48c...|2013-11-21 18:41:...|2013|   11|
|f83e30f9-950a-4b9...|2013-11-21 18:41:...|2013|   11|
|3425e4ea-b715-476...|2013-11-21 18:41:...|2013|   11|
|a20a6aeb-da4f-4fd...|2013-11-21 18:41:...|2013|   11|
|d2f57e6f-889b-49b...|2013-11-21 18:41:...|2013|   11|
|46f2eda5-408e-44e...|2013-11-21 18:41:...|2013|   11|
|36fb8b79-b2b5-493...|2013-11-21 18:41:...|2013|   11|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+-----+
only showing top 10 rows
```

**The create table in Hive:**

```
create external table if not exists t3(
  transactionid string,
  eventts timestamp)
partitioned by (year int, month int)
stored as parquet
location 's3://staging-dev/test/ttfourfieldspart2/';
```

**When I try to select some rows in Hive, it doesn't return any rows:**

```
hive> select * from t3 limit 10;
OK
Time taken: 0.027 seconds
hive>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I finally found the problem. When you create tables in Hive, where partitioned data already exists in S3 or HDFS, you need to run a command to update the Hive Metastore with the table's partition structure. Take a look here:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)

```
The commands are:

MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;


And on Hive running in Amazon EMR you can use:

ALTER TABLE table_name RECOVER PARTITIONS;
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. Brand new table, and before select would return any data, had to repair it... K... Thanks!

Comment: Rename the partition column to the one in complete lower cases: example - ```snapshotVersion``` should be renamed to ```snapshotversion``` in S3 Or HDFS and then ```MSCK REPAIR TABLE <tablename>``` command will fix this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this Question was answered already, the following point may also help the users who are still not able to solve the issue just by `MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;`

I have an hdfs file system which is  partitioned as below:

`<parquet_file>/<partition1>/<partition2>`

eg: `my_file.pq/column_5=test/column_6=5`

I created a hive table with partitions

eg:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE myschema.my_table(
`column_1` int,
`column_2` string,
`column_3` string,
`column_4` string
)
PARTITIONED BY (`column_5` string, `column_6` int) STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION
  'hdfs://u/users/iamr/my_file.pq'
```

After this, I repaired the schema partitions using the following command

`MSCK REPAIR TABLE myschema.my_table;`

After this it was started working for me.

Another thing I noticed was that, **while writing PARQUET files from spark, name the columns with lower case**, otherwise hive may not able to map it. For me after renaming the columns in PARQUET file, it started working

for eg: `my_file.pq/COLUMN_5=test/COLUMN_6=5` didn't worked for me

but `my_file.pq/column_5=test/column_6=5` worked

Comment: Worked like a charm!! renaming my partition column to lowercase completely resolved the issue.