# AmazonS3Client recursive GET request problem

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

My s3 bucket has 2 level nested directories (level 1 ~6000 directories, level 2 10-500 directories).
the problem is that when reading it with spark e.g `new SQLContext(sc).read.parquet(path)`
I'm getting slowdowns from s3 because of a massive amount of calls when listing the files.

I saw this post here that is dealing with a patch for that issue:
[Spark lists all leaf node even in partitioned data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39513505/spark-lists-all-leaf-node-even-in-partitioned-data)
and this issue here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13208

I was wondering if someone tried it successfully because I'm using Hadoop 2.9 and I'm still having this issue.

Steve Loughran, if you can respond to it I would be very thankful.

Comment: > Steve Loughran, if you can respond to it I would be very thankful.
other than "it's a bit presumptive to ask like that", and "I've discussed directory layouts elsewhere"  my answer is "upgrade to hadoop-3.2

Comment: @SteveLoughran Thank you for the response! as far as I know, there isn't a spark version that is supported in hadoop 3.2

Comment: there is if you build it yourself; use the hadoop-3.2 profile, that is maven with the settings: mvn install -DskipTests  -Phive -Pyarn -Phadoop-3.2 -Phadoop-cloud ... don't be afraid of building your own