# Hive unable to fetch data from partition created by Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-hdinsight

Current Setup:
1. HDInsight for Spark
2. Azure Datalake Store for HDFS storage

I am trying to load data into a hive table from the partition located on Azure DLS for writing to the partiton location I am using this code -

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.context import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sc = SparkContext(appName="Transformation").getOrCreate()
sql_context = SQLContext(sc)
sql_context.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
sql_context.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
sql_context.setConf("hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode", "400")
sql_context.setConf("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet", "false")

df = sql_context.read.orc("adl://LOCATION_NAME") # current data in ORC format stored on ADLS
df.write.format("parquet").partitionBy('ReportId', 'ReportDeliveryDate').save('adl://LOCATION_NAME') # writing the data
```

I can see the partition data at the location :
[image: Partitioned Data in ADLS Folder]

Now I am creating the table with the following command in Hive:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS default.test_tb;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.test_tb
(
A string,
B string,
)
PARTITIONED BY (ReportId STRING, ReportDeliveryDate STRING)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 'adl://LOCATION_NAME';
```

and when I am making this query - `select * from test_tb` there is no output.
I have tried many methods like one provided [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/writing-into-dynamic-partitions-using-spark-2e2b818a007a). Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

*----Update---*
The problem here is different, I had a long discussion with Azure Team and the problem was `HIVE` doesn't support `UpperCase` partitions so if you create them in `lowercase` from `spark` and then run `repair table command` it worked

Comment: yeah but the answer there still doesn't solve the problems @KirkBroadhurst

Comment: @NikhilParmar According to that question, this is a limitation of some versions of Spark. There is a workaround offered - did you try it?

Comment: yeah I tried it but now spark takes forever to dump data into partitions

Comment: Another similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551878/hive-doesnt-read-partitioned-parquet-files-generated-by-spark 
Suggest you  try looking at similar questions on the site.

Comment: Hey @kirk i think I need to try this last thing here I will update you soon on this

Comment: I'm leaving this opened for now.

Comment: Hey Guys @eliasah here the problem was different so was the solution. Let me update the answer